# Automatically cycle through full-page nodes

Tags: views, nodes, javascript

Looking to implement something that will loop through nodes in the system. I'm not looking for carousel functionality, but instead want to load/display full-page node content, wait, and then load/display the next node.

The end result should be kinda like a TV channel, presenting nodes of various content types on big TVs in the common areas of our building.

I've got some ideas for how to build this, but would like to ask if there is a module that already accomplishes something similar?

Comment: Since you can do exactly this with full display node views and flexslider or owl carousel, why wouldn't you?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to implement this feature and I had almost achieved it. To try-out, click any preview button in [this](http://dropthemes.in/gallery) page, you can see the content cycling through nodes.

I suppose you want to cycle through a list of nodes generated by a View.

**Procedure:**

I used [Views navigation](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_navigation) module to preserve the list of nodes generated in a View. It also preserves the order of those nodes in cache.

In script:

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.module = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {

      //Posts the current position of node and Views-navigation cache ID - on clicking 'next' button
      $("body", context).on("click", ".next", function() {
        var pos = $(this).attr('data-pos');
        var cid = $(this).attr('data-cid');
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/navigation',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: 'pos='+pos+'&cid='+cid+'&dir='+dir+'',
          success: DoWhateverWithNextNode
        });
      });

    },
  };
})(jQuery);
```

In module:

```
//Menu callback for 'navigation'
function get_next_node() {
  if($pos = $_POST['pos']) {
    module_load_include('inc', 'views_navigation', 'views_navigation');

    $result = views_navigation_get_result($_POST['cid']);
    $max_index = count($result) - 1;
    $pos = ($pos > $max_index) ? 0 : (($pos < 0) ? $max_index : $pos);

    if ($nid = $result[$pos]) {
      $next_node = node_load($nid);
      return drupal_json_output($next_node);
    }
  }
}
```

In *DoWhateverWithNextNode(data)*, you are required to increment 'data-pos' for '.next' element by 1. So that you can cycle through nodes.

P.S. This code may not be a working version. I just provided you an overview of my implementation.